# Finding a branch cut or a branch point

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, na.numerical-analysis, complex-dynamics

Is there a way to find a branch cut or a branch point, through which a curve over a complex function goes, or in general in some region of complex function, say $\ln(f(z))$, using numerical methods or any other approach, without solving $f(z)=0$?